# Always return 0 exit code

Tags: cypress

When running my Cypress tests I want to always return exit code 0. I run these tests after my release deployment so when it returns a non-zero exit code the test details doesn't report to the release summary. Many test runners have a configuration option to fail on an error or not, and so I am looking for that option. Haven't seen anything like that yet so please point me in that direction. If it doesn't exist I'll open a feature request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// likely want to do this in a support file
// so it's applied to all spec files
// cypress/support/index.js

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from
  // failing the test
  return false
})
```

[/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Uncaught-Exceptions](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Uncaught-Exceptions)